# Ubuntu 17.04 asked me to "update" my system and NVIDIA stopped working again

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, update-manager, cuda

Ubuntu 17.04 asked me for updating some packages to the current Ubuntu version on the 20th of August 2017 and NVIDIA stopped working completely. I spent several days trying to configure it for the first time (NVIDIA makes it painful, their support is terrible!!!) and now this "update" messed everything up again. When I open the NVIDIA X Server Settings, it doesn't even recognize my graphic card, **NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760M**. Now if I go to the *additional drivers* tab opening the `software-properties-gtk` (terminal command), I see the NVIDIA driver version I had (340.102) selected, but it is now marked as OpenSource instead of proprietary. In the Synaptic Package Manager, it says the current installed version is 340.102-0ubuntu3+gpu17.04.1, which is also marked as the newest. And this doesn't work at all! Opening the file */var/log/apt/history.log* , about the upgrades, I get:

```
Start-Date: 2017-08-20  21:08:11
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.130'
Install: gigedit:amd64 (2:1.0.0-3kxstudio3v5, automatic), linuxsampler:amd64 (2:2.0.0-1kxstudio3v5, automatic)
Upgrade: libffado2:amd64 (2.3.0-2, 2:2.3.0+svn2652-1~zesty1), update-manager-core:amd64 (1:17.04.3, 1:17.04.5), whoopsie:amd64 (0.2.55, 0.2.55.2), libfreerdp2:amd64 (2.0.0~git20170411.0.201704111144.59a8418-0~remmina0.201704091831~ubuntu17.04.1, 2.0.0~git20170720.0.201707200652.72cd36c-0~remmina0.201704091831~ubuntu17.04.1), grub-common:amd64 (2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.1, 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2), libcuda1-340:amd64 (340.102-0ubuntu3, 340.102-0ubuntu3+gpu17.04.1), patchage:amd64 (1.0.0~dfsg0-0.1build2, 1:1.0.1+svn5733-1kxstudio1v5), update-manager:amd64 (1:17.04.3, 1:17.04.5), libwhoopsie0:amd64 (0.2.55, 0.2.55.2), remmina-common:amd64 (1.2.0~rcgit.18-0~remmina1~zesty, 1.2.0-rcgit-19-0~remmina201707222041-r9d05738-d76b67cb~ubuntu17.04.1), sudo:amd64 (1.8.19p1-1ubuntu1.1, 1.8.19p1-1ubuntu1.2), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (59.0.3071.115-1, 60.0.3112.101-1), jackd2:amd64 (1.9.10+20150825git1ed50c92~dfsg-2ubuntu2, 2:1.9.11+git20170722-1~zesty2), grub2-common:amd64 (2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.1, 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2), libxnvctrl0:amd64 (384.47-0ubuntu0~gpu17.04.1, 384.59-0ubuntu0~gpu17.04.1), libwinpr2:amd64 (2.0.0~git20170411.0.201704111144.59a8418-0~remmina0.201704091831~ubuntu17.04.1, 2.0.0~git20170720.0.201707200652.72cd36c-0~remmina0.201704091831~ubuntu17.04.1), grub-efi-amd64-bin:amd64 (2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.1, 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2), remmina:amd64 (1.2.0~rcgit.18-0~remmina1~zesty, 1.2.0-rcgit-19-0~remmina201707222041-r9d05738-d76b67cb~ubuntu17.04.1), python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:17.04.8, 1:17.04.9), python3-update-manager:amd64 (1:17.04.3, 1:17.04.5), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:17.04.8, 1:17.04.9), session-shortcuts:amd64 (1.2, 1.2ubuntu0.17.04.1), libjack-jackd2-0:amd64 (1.9.10+20150825git1ed50c92~dfsg-2ubuntu2, 2:1.9.11+git20170722-1~zesty2), libjack-jackd2-0:i386 (1.9.10+20150825git1ed50c92~dfsg-2ubuntu2, 2:1.9.11+git20170722-1~zesty2), wine-stable:amd64 (2.0.1~zesty, 2.0.2~zesty), grub-efi-amd64:amd64 (2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.1, 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2), shim-signed:amd64 (1.28+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1, 1.32~17.04.1+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1), winehq-stable:amd64 (2.0.1~zesty, 2.0.2~zesty), remmina-plugin-rdp:amd64 (1.2.0~rcgit.18-0~remmina1~zesty, 1.2.0-rcgit-19-0~remmina201707222041-r9d05738-d76b67cb~ubuntu17.04.1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:amd64 (1:17.04.8, 1:17.04.9), qjackctl:amd64 (0.4.2-0ubuntu2, 2:0.4.5-1kxstudio1v5), grub-efi-amd64-signed:amd64 (1.80.1+2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.1, 1.80.2+2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2), snapd-login-service:amd64 (1.9-0ubuntu1, 1.13-0ubuntu0.17.04.1), jackd2-firewire:amd64 (1.9.10+20150825git1ed50c92~dfsg-2ubuntu2, 2:1.9.11+git20170722-1~zesty2), wine-stable-i386:i386 (2.0.1~zesty, 2.0.2~zesty), remmina-plugin-vnc:amd64 (1.2.0~rcgit.18-0~remmina1~zesty, 1.2.0-rcgit-19-0~remmina201707222041-r9d05738-d76b67cb~ubuntu17.04.1), libsnapd-glib1:amd64 (1.9-0ubuntu1, 1.13-0ubuntu0.17.04.1), qsampler:amd64 (0.4.2-2, 2:0.3.1-1kxstudio4v5), libfreerdp-client2:amd64 (2.0.0~git20170411.0.201704111144.59a8418-0~remmina0.201704091831~ubuntu17.04.1, 2.0.0~git20170720.0.201707200652.72cd36c-0~remmina0.201704091831~ubuntu17.04.1), wine-stable-amd64:amd64 (2.0.1~zesty, 2.0.2~zesty), nvidia-opencl-icd-340:amd64 (340.102-0ubuntu3, 340.102-0ubuntu3+gpu17.04.1), nvidia-340:amd64 (340.102-0ubuntu3, 340.102-0ubuntu3+gpu17.04.1), nvidia-settings:amd64 (384.47-0ubuntu0~gpu17.04.1, 384.59-0ubuntu0~gpu17.04.1)
```

[My old thread on configuring this NVIDIA card for the first time](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82528/how-to-make-cuda-work-in-ubuntu-so-as-to-enable-gpu-rendering-in-blender)

From what I've seen it is not even possible to undo an update in Ubuntu. What is wrong here? How could I solve this issue?